# Django: convert string to HTML is possible?

Tags: django, django-templates

I pass `string` variable  to django template as context variable:

```
my_var = "<h1> hihih </h1>"
```

In my template, I use `{{ my_var }}` and want to show it as `HTML`, not just `<h1> hihih </h1>`.

Is it possible?

(I don't need any other kind solution...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter for that:

```
{{ my_var|safe }}
```